# Is it possible to load a class without installing the APK?

Tags: android, classloader, apk

I would like to download an apk file from my application and store it in device memory and then load some class from the downloaded APK. Is this possible? I read it is only possible when we install the apk but is there no way to do this without installing the apk?

Comment: Why would you not want to install it?  I don't believe it is possible, as part of their sandbox security is most likely in the installation of the .apk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Is it possible to install an apk without any UI being displayed. I used to work on BB SDK where we have API to install an application seamlessly, do we have any such API in android?

Comment: Sure, you can have an activity that doesn't create an UIs, there are various approaches to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the update...Can you please point me the right direction of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To create an activity without a UI it makes sense to exit out of the Activity quickly and go to a `Service` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    final String token = retrieveToken();
    username = retrieveUsername();
    if (!isEmpty(token) && !isEmpty(username)) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("net.mine", "net.mine.Service");
            startService(i);
            conn = new RemoteServiceConnection();
            bindService(i, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

This isn't a complete example as I have some functions I didn't inline, but the basic idea should be here.

Basically, just start up and then go to an Android Service, as that is what should be used to run in the background, and then if you need to start up an Activity it can be done from there.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But my prob is that when I run my application it shouldnt have any UI but it should download an apk file from a web server and install it without user seeing progressbar or other UI

Comment: Downloading without the user knowing will be a problem, in terms of installing it, as the user needs to be able to approve it regardless.